# Deleting xml tags with particular Element name using xml.dom in python

Tags: python, xml, dom

How can we delete tags with particular Element name in an xml code using `xml.dom` (not `lxml.etree`) in python.

e.g. if we have the following xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
   <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
   <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   <genre>Computer</genre>
   <price>44.95</price>
   <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
   <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
   with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
   <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
   <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   <genre>Fantasy</genre>
   <price>5.95</price>
   <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
   <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
   an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
   of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
  <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
  society in England, the young survivors lay the 
  foundation for a new society.</description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk104">
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
  <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
  agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
  for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
  Ascendant.</description>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

How can we delete all the tags named `<title>` using `xml.dom` in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select all the elements by `title` tag and remove them using `removeChild`

**Update:**

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse("book_xml.xml")

nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("title")

for node in nodes:
    parent = node.parentNode
    parent.removeChild(node) 

print xmldoc.toxml()
```

You can also write new changes to xml file by :

```
with open("result.xml","w") as fs:
    fs.write(xmldoc.toxml())
    fs.close()
```

Comment: can you please explain how to use 'removeChild' here? Your code would just print the tags that I want to delete. Thanks.

Comment: Thank You so much. It(Update) works perfectly.(For future readers : 'doc_root' here is not required as we are not making use of it anywhere). Many thanks again.

Comment: see the updated code doc_root removed, file write also added.